# Removing elements and corresponding indices in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `A` and `B`. I want to remove the zero elements of `A` and the corresponding indices in `B`. I present the expected output.

```
A = [[210.9, 0.0, 1109.68564358, 383.43369921, 0.0]]
B=[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]]
```

The expected output is

```
Anew= [[210.9, 1109.68564358, 383.43369921]]
Bnew= [[(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 3)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are list of list, better to convert them to normal list first:

```
A = [[210.9, 0.0, 1109.68564358, 383.43369921, 0.0]]
B = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]]

# convert them to just list
A = A[0] 
B = B[0]

Anew = [a for a in A if a!=0.0]
Bnew = [b for a,b in zip(A,B) if a!=0.0]

# back to list of list, probably unnecessary.
Anew = [Anew] 
Bnew = [Bnew]
```

Anyway, for this sort of task it may be better to use pandas.